# finding the critical value for a specific alpha in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe, i.e. df:

```
df = 

 0.49

 0.31

 0.01

 0.1

 0.7

 0.71

 0.24

 0.05

 0.75

 0.79

 0.15

 0.29

 0.34

 0.17

 0.1
```

I want to find a critical value at its 5% significance level.

For instance, if 0.2 is the critical value at 5% significant level, I would say values below 0.2 are not statistically significant. Is there any function in pandas dataframe or python for finding such a threshold or critical value? Thanks.

Comment: *I have one dataframe* - show that dataframe and the expected result to get a quick help

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanks. I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

What you provided doesn't even seem as a dataframe to me. Maybe the following code would get you on a right track:

```
#create random data and their critical values
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({"Value": pd.Series(random.sample(range(0,100),15)),
                   "Critical": pd.Series(random.sample(range(100,3000),15))})[["Value","Critical"]]

# print whole dataframe
print df

    Value  Critical
0      78       966
1      18      1595
2      88       963
3      24      2927
4      47      1082
5      26      2425
6      36      2847
7       0       143
8      73      1205
9      65       638
10     92       341
11     27       213
12     21      1531
13     44       590
14     28       584

# select only those with value bigger that 5% of its critical value
df = df[df["Value"]>df["Critical"]*0.05]

# print criticals only
print df

    Value  Critical
0      78       966
2      88       963
8      73      1205
9      65       638
10     92       341
11     27       213
13     44       590
```